# How to improve the performance of $facet stage in Aggregation Pipeline in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, query-optimization, mongo-shell

I had written a MongoDB aggregation pipeline in C#. I was able to obtain the correct result initially. However, after a couple of months, the dataset grew larger, and the aggregation started to perform very slowly. While the `$match` stage, benefiting from an index, continued to deliver fast results, the issue was observed with the `$facet` stage.

```
{
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              PropertyAddressState: {
                $eq: "OH",
              },
              PropertyAddressCity: {
                $eq: "DAYTON",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              PropertyAddressState: {
                $eq: "CA",
              },
              PropertyAddressCity: {
                $eq: "LOS ANGELES",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
{
    $facet: {
      results: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            tax_delinquent: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsTaxDelinquent",
              },
            },
            absentee_owners: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsAbsenteeOwners",
              },
            },
            out_of_state_owners: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsOutOfStateOwners",
              },
            },
            purchased_2010_2012: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsPurchasedin20102012",
              },
            },
            multi_family_owners: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsMultiFamilyOwners",
              },
            },
            properties_in_a_trust: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsPropertiesInATrust",
              },
            },
            vacant: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsVacant",
              },
            },
            land_residential: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsLand",
              },
            },
            pre_foreclosure: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: "$IsPreforecloure",
              },
            },
            pre_foreclosure_purchased_2010_2012: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: {
                  $and: [
                    "$IsPreforecloure",
                    "$IsPurchasedin20102012",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            pre_foreclosure_out_of_state: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: {
                  $and: [
                    "$IsPreforecloure",
                    "$IsOutOfStateOwners",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            pre_foreclosure_vacant: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: {
                  $and: [
                    "$IsPreforecloure",
                    "$IsVacant",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            absentee_owners_purchased_2010_2012: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: {
                  $and: [
                    "$IsAbsenteeOwners",
                    "$IsPurchasedin20102012",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
            out_of_state_purchased_2010_2012: {
              $sum: {
                $toInt: {
                  $and: [
                    "$IsOutOfStateOwners",
                    "$IsPurchasedin20102012",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      absentee_owners_with_multiple_properties_vacant:
        [
          {
            $match: {
              IsAbsenteeOwners: true,
              IsVacant: true,
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$PartyOwner1NameFull",
              count: {
                $sum: 1,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $match: {
              _id: {
                $ne: null,
              },
              count: {
                $gte: 2,
                $lte: 10000,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $count: "count",
          },
        ],
      absentee_owners_multiple_properties: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsAbsenteeOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$PartyOwner1NameFull",
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $ne: null,
            },
            count: {
              $gte: 2,
              $lte: 10000,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

This is the execution stats for the above aggregation.

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 518601,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 34743,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 582076,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 518601,
```

The response for the above aggregation is like this.

```
results: 
     Array (1) 
       Object _id: null 
tax_delinquent: 2619 
absentee owners: 32681
out_of_state_owners: 2415 
purchased_2010_2012: 11543 
multi_family_owners: 20944
properties_in_a_trust: 10484
vacant: 1230
land residential: 4173
pre_foreclosure: 38854
pre_foreclosure_purchased_201: 4893
absentee_owners_with_multiple: 
    Array (1) 
       Object count: 18
absentee_owners_multiple_prop:
    Array (1) 
      Object count: 1801
```

In the provided aggregation, I implemented a `$group` stage within the `$facet`. Consequently, I removed the `$group` stage and attempted parallel processing by separating each category inside `$facet`.

```
IsTaxDelinquent: Array (1)
    • 0: Object count: 2619 
IsAbsenteeOwners: Array (1)
    • 0: Object count: 32681
IsOut0f5tateOwners: Array (1) 
    • 0: Object count: 2415 
IsPurchasedin20102012: Array (1) 
    • 0: Object count: 11543 
IsMultiFamilyOwners: Array (1) 
IsPropertiesInATrust: Array (1)
IsVacant: Array (1)
IsLand: Array (1) 
IsPreforecloure: Array (1) 
pre_foreclosure_purchased_2010_2012: Array (1) 
pre_foreclosure_out_of_state: Array (1) 
pre_foreclosure_vacant: Array (1) 
absentee_owners_vacant: Array (1) 
out_of_state_vacant: Array (1) 
vacant_purchased_2010_2012: Array (1) absentee_owners_with_multiple_properties_vacant: Array (1)
```

```
{
    $facet: {
      IsTaxDelinquent: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsTaxDelinquent: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsAbsenteeOwners: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsAbsenteeOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsOutOfStateOwners: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsOutOfStateOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsPurchasedin20102012: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsPurchasedin20102012: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsMultiFamilyOwners: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsMultiFamilyOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsPropertiesInATrust: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsPropertiesInATrust: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsVacant: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsVacant: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsLand: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsLand: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      IsPreforecloure: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsPreforecloure: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      pre_foreclosure_purchased_2010_2012: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsOutOfStateOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      pre_foreclosure_purchased_2010_2012: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                IsPreforecloure: true,
              },
              {
                IsPurchasedin20102012: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
      absentee_owners_with_multiple_properties_vacant:
        [
          {
            $match: {
              IsAbsenteeOwners: true,
              IsVacant: true,
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$PartyOwner1NameFull",
              count: {
                $sum: 1,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $match: {
              _id: {
                $ne: null,
              },
              count: {
                $gte: 2,
                $lte: 10000,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $count: "count",
          },
        ],
      absentee_owners_multiple_properties: [
        {
          $match: {
            IsAbsenteeOwners: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$PartyOwner1NameFull",
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            _id: {
              $ne: null,
            },
            count: {
              $gte: 2,
              $lte: 10000,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $count: "count",
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

Despite producing accurate results, this approach still resulted in slow loading times. I’m inquiring whether there exists a more effective method to achieve results using the `$facet` stage.

I’m using MongoDB version 4.4.

Below I have set up a sample data set with the necessary fields for testing purposes

[temp_tax_data2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oy1b-cyZ6AC4wrmNjkKNG51ObNb4zvAA/view)

Comment: Can [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/) help you?

Comment: @Valijon I was adding only two filters in the $match stage, but there are additional filters that the results are based on.